Writing gauge transformation of the gauge fields explicitly in terms of coordinates
Let $G$ be a non-Abelian simple compact gauge group and $\{ t^\alpha\}$ be a normalized set of generators for its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $C^{\alpha \beta}_\gamma$ be the coupling constant for this set of generators:
\begin{equation}
[ t^\alpha , t^\beta] = C^{\alpha \beta}_\gamma t^\gamma \text{ where } [,] \text{ is the Lie bracket for } \mathfrak{g}
\end{equation}
Now, Let $A:= \bigl( A_{\alpha \mu} t^\alpha \bigr)_{\mu=0,1,2,3}$ be the gauge field for this theory with $i$ labeling the spacetime components.
Then, it is said that $A$ is in the adjoint representation of $G$, so that the local action of $G$ on $A$ is given by the formula
\begin{equation}
A_{\alpha \mu} t^\alpha \to A_{\alpha \mu} \bigl( g t^\alpha g^{-1} \bigr) -  i \bigl[\partial_\mu g \bigr]g^{-1}
\end{equation}
where $g$ is any local $G$-valued mapping.
However, the right-hand side of the above formula has $g$ multiplied to $t^\alpha$ as well as the term $[\partial_\mu g]g^{-1}$ not explicitly expanded with respect to  $\{t^\alpha\}$.
So, my question is

What would be explicit expressions for the "coeffients" (with $\alpha$ and $\mu$ indices) of the right-hand side of the above formula with respect to $\{t^\alpha\}$?

Could anyone please help me? I guess $g$ should somehow be expressed in terms of  $\{t^\alpha\}$.

Assume a field $\psi(x)$ transforming with respect to some arbitrary representation $$U(x)=e^{-i \alpha_a(x) T_a}, \qquad [T_a,T_b]= i f_{abc}T_c$$ of your gauge group. Defining the matrix-valued gauge field $$A_\mu(x) = A_{a \mu}(x) T_a,$$ the condition for the invariance of the Lagrangean under a local gauge transformation  $$D_\mu \psi(x) =(\partial_\mu +i g A_\mu(x)) \psi (x) \to (\partial_\mu +i g A_\mu^\prime(x))U(x) \psi(x) =U(x) D_\mu \psi(x)$$ requires $$A_\mu^\prime(x) = U(x) A_\mu(x) U^{-1}(x)+\frac{i}{g}(\partial_\mu U(x)) U^{-1}(x).$$ The goal is now to show that $A_\mu^\prime(x)$ can indeed be written as a  linear combination of the generators, $$A_\mu^\prime(x) =T_a A_{a\mu}^\prime(x).$$
To this end, we consider $X(t)= e^{-itY} X e^{itY}$ with square matrices $X,Y$. $X(t)$ fulfills the differential equation $$\dot{X}(t)=-i [Y,X(t)]$$ with the initial condition $X(0)=X$. Defining the operator $({\rm ad}Y) X :=[Y,X]$ acting on the space of matrices, the differential equation can be written in the form $$\dot{X}(t) =-i ({\rm ad}Y)X(t)$$ with the solution $$X(t) = e^{-i t \,{\rm ad}Y}\underbrace{X(0)}_X.$$ Thus $$\begin{align} e^{-iY}Xe^{iY}=X(1) &=e^{-i \, {\rm ad}Y}X \\[5pt] &=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-i)^n}{n!}({\rm ad} Y)^n \\[5pt] &=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-i)^n}{n!} \underbrace{[Y,[Y,\ldots[Y,X]\ldots]}_{n-{\rm fold \;commutator}}.\end{align}$$
Applying this formula to $X=T_a$ and $Y= \alpha_b T_b =: \alpha \cdot T$, we find $$\begin{align}e^{-i \alpha \cdot T} T_a e^{i \alpha \cdot T}&= e^{-i \, {\rm ad}\alpha \cdot T}T_a \\[5pt] &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-i)^n}{n!}[\alpha\cdot T , [\alpha \cdot T,, \ldots[\alpha \cdot T,T_a]\ldots],      \end{align}$$ with $$\begin{align}({\rm ad} \, \alpha \cdot T) T_a &= [\alpha_b T_b, T_a] \\[5pt]&=\alpha_b i f_{bac}T_c \\[5pt]&= T_c \alpha_b \underbrace{(-i f_{bca})}_{(t_b)_{ca}},  \end{align}$$ where $t_b$ are the generators in the adjoint representation. Thus we arrive at $$ e^{-i \alpha \cdot T} T_a e^{i \alpha \cdot T}= T_c (e^{-i \alpha_b t_b})_{ca},$$  yielding $$\begin{align} U(x) A_\mu(x) U^{-1}(x) &= e^{-i \alpha(x) \cdot T}T_a A_{a \mu}(x)e^{i \alpha(x) \cdot T} \\[5pt] &=T_c (e^{-i \alpha_b t_b})_{ca}A_{a \mu},\end{align}$$ showing the desired result for the first term of $A_\mu^\prime(x)$.
For the second term, we write $$U(x+t e(\mu))U^{-1}(x)=e^{-i \alpha_a(x+t e(\mu))T_a} e^{\alpha_b(x)T_b}=e^{-i \beta_a(x,t)T_a},$$ where $e(\mu)$ denotes a unit vector in $\mu$-direction $U(x)U^{-1}(x)=1$ implies $\beta_b(x,0)=0$ and $$\frac{d}{dt} U(x+te(\mu))U^{-1}(x) \large|_{t=0} =-i \frac{\partial \beta_a(x,t)}{\partial t} \large|_{t=0} T_a,$$ finishing the proof.

The left side of your fifth formula should be $A'_{\mu}$. I guess you made a typo?

@Keith Thanks, already corrected.

May I ask what you exactly mean by $\beta$ in the last two formulas? You seem to assume that any element of $G$ can be written in the form of a "single" (rather than products of) exponential. Is this true?

@Keith The product of the two group elements $e^{-i \alpha_a(x+t e(\mu)) T_a}$ and $e^{i\alpha_b(x)  T_b}$ is again a group element (in the chosen representation) and can thus be written in the form $e^{-i \beta_a(x,t)  T_a}$, i.e. $\beta_a(x,t)$ are the "coordinates" of this group element.

Yes, I wonder if this is indeed true. I guess because $G$ is connected and compact? Anyway, I wonder if we can go further and express $\beta_a$ or $\partial_t \beta_a$ (at $t=0$) in terms of $\alpha_a$.

The $g$ as in $D_\mu \psi(x) =(\partial_\mu +i g A_\mu(x)) \psi (x)$ is NOT the $g$ as in OP's $\bigl[\partial_\mu g \bigr]g^{-1}$. Is the intension to throw a curve ball or just to spice it up a bit?

@MadMad The $g$ in my answer is the coupling constant of the gauge theory and not the group element as in OP.

Your derivative term should be
$$
 (\partial_\mu g) g^{-1}.
$$
This combination is an element of the Lie algebra,and so expressible as a sum of the $t^\alpha$, unlike the group element $g$ itself.
It's worth working this out for su(2) using
$$
g= x_0\mathbb I +i x_1 \sigma_1+ i x_2 \sigma_2+i x_3 \sigma_3
$$
Here $x_0^2+ x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1$ and the $x_i$ are real.
The identity matrix in $x_0\mathbb I$ shows that $g$ is not a sum of the generators.
If you compute $(\partial_\mu g) g^{-1}$, however,  you will find that the terms involving $\mathbb I$ drop out.
Combinations like $g^{-1} dg$ or $(dg)g^{-1}$ are called Maurer-Cartan forms.

Yes, it was a typo and I just fixed it. Could you help me with the original question?

I'm not sure what you want...  There are no simple formulae in Lie groups other than su(2). You need to choose coordinates in the Lie group manifold,  and do a lot of algebra.

If I write the right-hand side as $A'{\alpha \mu}t^{\alpha}$, how would $A'{\alpha \mu}$ be expressed in terms of $A_{\alpha \mu}$ and $g$?

Does this clarify my issue to you?

Firstly You need to be able to compute the matrix $ [Ad(g)]_b^a$ giving the  "adjoint" action $g^{-1}t^a g = t^b [Ad(g)]_b^a$ from the knowing the structure constants. This is not easy in anything other than su(2), where it is correponding O(3) matrix. The Maurer cartan's can be computed in su(2) using Euler angles.  But why do you need an explicit formula?

In physics textbooks like Weinberg vol 2, they write such formulas for "infinitesimal" transformations. I want to see what would be like for a finite case.
